# String interpolation prints variable name instead of variable contents

Tags: ruby, class, string-interpolation

I have a class like this:

```
class Example
    def printThisVar(printThing)
        print 'this is the var: #{printThing}'   
    end
end
```

However, the string that is printed is printed is `"this is the var: #{printThing}"` not `"this is the var: exampleText"`.

Is there any way to fix this?  thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is the case? I tested your code with `Example.new.printThisVar("exampleText\n")` and it behaved as expected.

Comment: Running your code in ruby 2.0 and 1.8 worked fine for me. Perhaps `print` is being overloaded somewhere in your code. Have you tried using `puts` instead of `print`?

Comment: @Max yeah - it's weird I just figured out that it doesn't work when I save it to a file and run via Terminal I get that error... But if I do it via irb, then I don't...

Comment: @Max I guess I switched from '' to "" subconsciously - thanks though

Comment: @Matt I guess I switched from '' to "" subconsciously - thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have single quotes instead of double quotes around the string you want to `print`.

```
class Example
    def print_this_var(print_thing)
        print 'this is the var: #{print_thing}'
    end
end

foo = Example.new
foo.print_this_var("example_text")

#=> this is the var: #{print_thing}
```

Changing the method definition to

```
        print "this is the var: #{print_thing}"
```

yields

```
#=> this is the var: example_text
```

String interpolation doesn't work with single quotes.

Comment: thanks - is there a reason you need "" compared to ''?

Comment: @user22138 only double-quote strings allow interpolation, see [Ruby Literals - Strings](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings)